# Trying to setup a subdomain... how do I setup DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I have a dev environment and a production environment.

The production environment lives at `example.com` on one server (77.123.45.67).

On a totally separate server (different host, everything), I have `dev.example.com` (77.765.43.21).

I'm trying to create a subdomain on the development server: `dev2.dev.example.com`.  I tried to add an entry to the dev DNS zone file:

```
dev2.dev.example.com CNAME dev.example.com
```

But, it is still not working. Do I have to do anything else, or is what I've done wrong?

Comment: Show your existing DNS configuration.

Comment: There _is_ a fairly common error in what you write; but [since we know that you are lying to us about your domain names and DNS data, we have no way to know whether that really is the problem, nor any reason to expend time on it](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-obscure-your-dns-data.html).

Answer (score 2):

your whole approach seems kind of odd but if you insist on creating a sub-domain named dev2.dev.example.com go ahead and edit the DNS with an A record for it.

dev2.dev         77.765.43.21

Next you need to edit the Apache.conf file and add dev2.dev.example.com as either a "ServerName" or "ServerAlias".

Answer (score 1):

You don't add an entry to the `dev` zone. In fact you shouldn't even have a `dev` zone. Everything should be done in `example` zone.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can take here:

1. keep everything in the example.com zone file, or
2. delegate dev.example.com to a separate name server.

Option 1 is simple: you keep everything in the same file, and there's no need to set up a second server. The disadvantage is that your production and development DNS settings are in the same file, which may not be what you want -- especially if you're as prone to typo'ing config files as I am!

If you go this route, your zone file should look something like this:
    # example.com
    # SOA, NS, etc.

```
@        IN A       77.123.45.67
dev      IN A       77.765.43.21
dev2.dev IN CNAME   dev
```

If you don't terminate a label with a dot character, the zone name is automatically appended.

Option 2 is a bit more complicated: you need to set up a second DNS server to host the dev.example.com domain. If you're trying to replicate a production environment, this could be what you want. It would look like this, assuming that your second nameserver lives on 1.2.3.4:

```
# example.com
# SOA, NS, etc. 

@        IN A       77.123.45.67
dev      IN NS      1.2.3.4
```

and for the other zone:

```
# dev.example.com
# SOA, NS, etc.
@        IN A       77.765.43.21
dev2     IN A       77.765.43.21
```

This delegates authority over the entire dev.example.com domain to nameserver 1.2.3.4, in the same manner that .com delegates example.com to your current nameserver.